# Theta Notation and Worst Case Running time nested loops

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, nested-loops, big-o

This is the code I need to analyse:

```
i = 1
while i < n
  do
    j = 0;
    while j <= i
       do
          j = j + 1
    i = 2i
```

So, the first loop should run log(2,n) and the innermost loop should run log(2,n) * (i + 1), but I'm pretty sure that's wrong. 
How do I use a theta notation to prove it?

Answer (score 3):

An intuitive way to think about this is to see how much work your *inner* loop is doing for a fixed value of *outer loop variable `i`*. It's clearly as much as *i* itself. Thus, if the value of *i* is 256, then then you will do `j = j + 1` that many times.

Thus, total work done is the sum of the values that *i* takes in the outer loop's execution. That variable is increasing much rapidly to catch up with *n*. Its values, as given by `i = 2i` (it should be `i = 2*i`), are going to be like: `2, 4, 8, 16, ...`, because we start with 2 iterations of the inner loop when `i = 1`. This is a geometric series: `a, ar, ar^2 ...` with `a = 1` and `r = 2`. The last term, as you figured out will be `n` and there will be `log2 n` terms in the series. And that is simple summation of a geometric series.

It doesn't make much sense to have a worst case or a best case for this algorithm because there are no different permutations of the input which is just a number `n` in this case. Best case or worst case are relevant when a particular input (e.g. a particular sequence of numbers) affects the running time of the algorithm.

The running time then is the [sum of geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) (`a.(r^num_terms - 1)/(r-1)`):

```
T(n) = 2 + 4 + ... 2^(log2 n)
     = 2 . (2^log2 n - 1)
     = 2 . (n - 1)
     ⩽ 3n = O(n)
```

Thus, you can't be doing work that is more than some constant multiple of n. Hence, the running time of this algorithm is `O(n)`.

You can't be doing some work that is less than some (other) constant multiple of n, since you have to go through the increment in inner loop as shown above. Thus, the running time of this algorithm is also ≥ c.n i.e. it is `Ω(n)`.

Together, this means that running time of this algorithm is `Θ(n)`.

Comment: aight, so the worst case running time is just the number of times the innermost loop will run, correct? and how do I use a theta notation to prove it?

Comment: @Chris I have updated it for completeness, let me know if it is clear (you can say so by accepting the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `i` in your final expression; only `n`.

You can easily see that the inner loop executes `i` times each time it is reached.  And it sounds like you've figured out the different values that `i` can have.  So add up those values, and you have the total amount of work.